# Spring controller returns html instead of a String

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, controller

I'm supposed to send the controller so it can run it and retun the result.
But what I get from the controller is the HTML code of the page I'm on.

```
self.runCode = function(){
    var content = "<?php echo 'Hello World !'; ?>";
    console.log(content);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myPage",
        data: content,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Impossible"+ e);
        }
    });                        
};


@Controller
public class RunController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String executePHP(@RequestBody String content) throws ScriptException{

        String result;
        result = Document.executeContent(content);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried to send data as JSON but that didn't seem to help, when I print on a console the result ( succes ) it keeps retuning the html code of /myPage.

Comment: Try adding `contentType:'application/json'` to ajax

Comment: Your question raised few questions on my end. **1.** Where did you get the `Document` package from? **2.** Which Java EE server are you running the script on? **3.** Is the JavaScript snippet in the JSP page?

Comment: 1- From a text editor on my web page ( console.log(content); displays the right thing )
2- Tomcat
3- I'm using AngularJS on the front-end, so no JSPs.

Comment: You are trying to execute a PHP script on a server that do not support PHP. That is the reason you're seeing HTML codes. There are couple of ways to run PHP on Tomcat. **1.**  Install Apache HTTPD server and then do a AJAX call to that URL, **2** Install PHP support on Tomcat7 or earlier.

Comment: @jmsweb
I've just found a library called "php-in-java". It works fine and I now get the result, but I'd like to get a result indicating where mistakes were done in case of syntax errors, do you have an idea ?

Comment: I'm assume you're referring to Quercus. You can initialize the loaded configuration file, `php.ini`, in `web.xml` deployment descriptor. If not using Quercus, you'll need to find a way to locate or integrate the `php.ini` that would allow you to enable or disable error output, i.e, `error_reporting = E_ALL`. This should display PHP errors.